# Problem with formatting PHP code within VsCode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am running Windows 10 latest version and VsCode latest version. I'm setting up a website using a PHP framework. Natively there seems no formatting support for PHP so I turned to plugins. I tried 'Format HTML in PHP' and that does exactly what it says - a page of HTML in a file with a .php extension is formatted on save. However when I try to format say a Controller, either on save or by pressing Alt-Shift-F, absolutely nothing happens. I have tried installing 'PHPfmt', 'PHP Intelephense, and 'Prettier' but in each case any attempt to format the Controller (Alt-Shift-F) failed to change anything. Yes I did restart the editor in every case. Can anyone suggest why this is not working or a plugin better than the ones I have tried? Is 'Format HTML in PHP' incompatible with the other plugins? I have really spent a long time on this and got nowhere.

Comment: You probably want the one referenced by the official intellisense plugin which is this one - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=junstyle.php-cs-fixer

Comment: I have eventually managed to make this work but what a performance! First I had to install the package using Composer. Then I had to install a separate file. Then I had to install the right VSCode plugin (there were several with the same name). Then I had to sort out the executable path for which there was zero or incorrect guidance online. I rather hope that editor plugins work out of the box so this was a big disappointment. Even after I've got it working it sets the indent to a relentless 4 spaces and there seems no way to change it. Probably 4 hours work and counting. Sigh!

Comment: Tough? VScode was not made with other langs in mind, it's based on electron with a focus on front-end web langs and C/C++. If you don't like the fact it takes effort to config your workflow, contribute to the extension repo and make a powershell script to do it for you?

Comment: As for the default 4 space tab thing, that is intentional, because that is what PHP's coding standards are and have been since 2012. First in coding standard [PSR2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) (now deprecated) and again in [PSR12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) - `"Code MUST use an indent of 4 spaces for each indent level, and MUST NOT use tabs for indenting."` If you want to change it, fine, but you risk breaking autoloading / other features especially if you use any frameworks.

Comment: Thanks very much for all this useful and helpful comment. I was not aware of the PSR12 standard for indentation.